# Invoke delegate in unity's main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, delegates

I have a correctly set upped delegate that I want to invoke in the main thread from a worker thread, how do I do so?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The problem is that I MUST stick with .NET 2.0 in unity, so I can't use the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you're using coroutines unity does the magic of thread management by itself . Just call whatever you need. If you're using System.Threading it's absolutely the same as in the MSDN documentation on threading.

Comment: As the previous comment states, in some cases Unity3d will do this for you. In other cases, you can use `SynchronizationContext` to invoke a delegate on the correct thread (i.e. get the context in the main thread, and then use that object later to invoke the delegate, per the answer in the marked duplicate). Another way is to create a queue of delegates yourself, and have code in the main thread that reads from the queue and invokes the delegates. It's more effort but will work as well.